# Install issues with Ricoh SP 211

Tags: drivers, printing, 15.10, ricoh

im trying to install a Ricoh SP211 Printer on Ubuntu 15.10.

The howto from: https://github.com/madlynx/ricoh-sp100/blob/master/INSTALL
Is helping me but i got stuck there.

When i run `./check-requirements` i get:

```
pbmtojbg     [REQUIRED] : No
identify     [REQUIRED] : Yes, version: Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2015-08-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
Ghostscript  [REQUIRED] : Yes, version: 9.16
ps2write     [REQUIRED] : Yes
pbmraw       [REQUIRED] : Yes
inotify-wait [optional] : No
```

Where do I get the packages `ps2write` and `pgmraw`?

By coincidence I found that `ps2write` is a package containing in imagemagick.

The other 2 I can't find. Come someone help me?

Best regards

Comment: pbmtojbg *required* No, sorry you cant install the thing. Also sudo apt-get install ps2write pbmraw

Answer (score 3):

> Where do I get the packages ps2write and pgmraw?

The program you are trying to install here check for the package called `gs` (i.e Ghostscript) and if you have installed this (which I can see you already have) you are good to go. You don't have to look for `ps2write` or `pgmraw` pacakges.

I see you do not have `pbmtojbg` (which is in fact not a requirement). But if you want to install this program, you have to install `jbigkit-bin` after [enabling the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository).

Answer (score 0):

SP211 driver for linux do exist...
search for "sp221 drivers" (221, not 211) and then download and extract the ubuntu drivers from ricoh website (it's an .exe you might need windows to unpack)
then install the .deb file, select SP221 in cups and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

As @nasdak said, it works with the sp221 driver. Here's how you do it:

1. extract the exe --> you'll get a deb --> extract that one as well (with archive manager or something similar). From the extracted:
2. move the file from data/usr/lib (follow the folder trail) to your cups filter folder (usually /usr/lib/cups/filter)
3. open cups with a browser (usually http://localhost:631, requires your computer user and pass) --> add printer --> select the ppd from data/user/share...
4. print

Answer (score 0):

There is a Forked PPA with installation instructions, I have forked it from the original contributor. Hope it helps.
https://github.com/biplabro/ricoh-sp100/blob/master/INSTALL

Install required libraries:

```
sudo apt install jbigkit-bin
```

and

```
sudo apt install inotify-tools
```

I have recently installed the drivers again. Tested & working in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: OP asks where to get the "unavailable components". I did not find them at your link...