# ricoh sp 212sfnw drivers install

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, sane, ricoh

I'm using ubuntu 16.04. I bought a new  ricoh sp 212sfnw it is a printer ,scanner, fax ,network and wireless printer.
I can't find or install drivers for printer or scanner or network .

**I tried this way :**

1. connect it via USB
2. Printers -> Add -> ricoh sp 212sfnw -> ricoh
3. there a list of many models for ricoh printers but i didn't find sp 212
4. I tried many different models but all working very slow .

**one solution for printer driver :**

selecting "Generic" -> "PCL 6/PCL XL" looks to work better.
The printer working good even via wifi

**scanner :**

`sudo sane-find-scanner` show this:

> # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the   # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your   # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.
>
> # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make
>   sure that   # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI
>   adapter.
>
> found USB scanner (vendor=0x05ca [RICOH ], product=0x044f [RICOH SP
>   212SFNw]) at libusb:001:002
>
> ```
> # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by   
> # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.
> ```
>
> # Not checking for parallel port scanners.
>
> # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary
>   ports   # can't be detected by this program.

`scanimage -L` show that :

> No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something
>   different, check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and
>   detected by the sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read
>   the documentation which came with this software (README, FAQ,
>   manpages).

I did that `sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` and added

> ```
> # RICOH SP 212SFNW 
> ATTRS{idVendor}=="05ca", ATTRS{idProduct}=="044f, ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
> ```

and that `sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/ricoh.conf` and added

```
#RICOH SP 212SFNw
usb 0x05ca 0x044f
```

But the same results I didn't find any way to install it

**How to install driver for scanner in details please ?**

Comment: The printer driver and wireless printer working well now but the problem in scanner driver

Comment: This printer is not officially supported via OpenPrint or CUPS.  You can use the [Generic Ricoh Postscript](http://www.openprinting.org/driver/Postscript-Ricoh/), but there will never be full functionality.  As for the scanner, you will find that there is no OEM driver for this unit.  There are possible hacked together fixes, including [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1793512).  I would not expect to get this scanner to work properly.

Comment: I tried this before and it didn't work as addition information may help the Windows driver is called Twain driver (kind of general drivers for many scanners )

Comment: Related:http://askubuntu.com/questions/711177/install-issues-with-ricoh-sp-211?rq=1

Comment: @ThatGuy ( sudo tee -a  ) this part ganging the terminal and do nothing how i can edit that